# Object Lock for unique values

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Hi I have one synchronized method which returns ms. Can anyone tell whether where each object will get the unique value in below code.

```
public static synchronized Long generateIdforDCR() 
         {  
        int val= return System.nanoTime();
        }
```

Call will be in another class like

```
forloop 1... 1000
{
   ClassName cn=new ClassName();
   cn.generateIdforDCR();

}
```

Will i get unique value always.

Comment: Synchronization has nothing to do it with it. (Also `nanoTime` returns a `long`. If your system is _really_ fast, it might return the same values twice.

Comment: Why is the return type `String` for the method actually returning `long`?

Comment: Don't call static methods on class instances. just call `ClassName.generateIdforDCR();`

Comment: Hi Thanks, Actually i am getting 2 duplicates among 500 records. means 2 duplicate val. Can this be the reason

Answer (score 1):

No - there's no guarantee that each call will return a different value. It's not inconceivable that the call (including synchronization) could take less time than the granularity of the internal clock used for `nanoTime()`. (Indeed, I can see this happen on my laptop.)

It sounds like you should just be using an [`AtomicLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) instead:

```
private static final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

public static Long generateIdforDCR() {
    return counter.incrementAndGet();
}
```

That will give you a unique number (if you call it fewer than 2<sup>64</sup> times) *within that run*. If you need it to be unique within a larger scope (e.g. across multiple sequential runs, or potentially multiple concurrent runs of different processes) then you'll need a slightly different approach.

Comment: @Champ23: What do you mean by "that" issue? Your current code is broken, and you should change it. I've given you details of an approach and its limitations, but you've given us no context in terms of what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks, its already implemented, so getting duplicate. just want to know is this the cause calling synchronized function with object.